# node.js: как избежать большой вложенности при асинхронных запросах?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Не так давно стал изучать JS, TypeScript, платформу node.js

Асинхронность событий ввода/вывода и однопоточность - классная идея, но меня как "классика" сильно смущает получающаяся многовложенность кода. То есть, конструкции наподобие:

```
network.receive(..., function(data) {
    if (data.command == 'logon')
        access.check('logon', function(result) {
            if (result == true) {
                log.add('call logon')
                db.sql('select ...', function(err, row) {
                    log.add('logon success')
                    network.send(data.address, 'success', function(res) {
                        if (res...) ...
                    }.bind(this))
                }.bind(this))
            }
        }.bind(this))
}.bind(this))
```

Вот этот код лесенкой прямо раздражает :) И эти бесконечные bind'ы. Конечно, пример я утрировал, но, думаю, жалоба ясна.

Может быть это во мне играют старые привычки? Есть какая то концепция написания кода, чтобы он был более аккуратным, красивым? Например, мне очень непривычно, что если я написал на TypeScript свой класс и вызываю его как-то так:

```
var result = new MyClass.search(...)
```

То метод search() вызовется раньше, чем завершится работа конструктора, если в конструкторе приходится использовать асинхронные функции. То есть, конструктор еще не полностью закончил инициализацию объекта, а кто-то уже вызывает методы объекта. Можно ли сделать что-то подобное в реализации (аналог провожу с windows API):

```
search(...) {
    waitForSingleObject(event)
    ...
}
```

И пока конструктор не сделает свою работу и не вызовет:
    setEvent(event)
то выполнение метода search() притормозиться? При этом, конечно, waitForSingleObject() должна быть умной функцией и давать понять потоку, что пока можно заняться другими делами и не тормозить, допустим, всю платформу node.js?

P.S. Извините, что так много букв.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall):

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Некоторые другие методы из этой библиотеки тоже наверняка понадобятся.

Answer (score 1):

Оберните в Promises (это избавит от вложенности) и используйте стрелочные функции (это избавит от bind'ов).